# La conexión no es privada, usando Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, google-chrome, windows7

He estado atorado con un problema el cual no tengo idea que pueda ser, explico:

Yo trabajo con Laravel y utilizo Homestead para desarrollo local, todo era perfecto hasta que después de actualizar windows, google chrome ya no me deja acceder a la página que estoy desarrollando, me dice que la conexión no es privada, no estoy seguro si deba hacer una configuración extra en el sistema operativo. A continuación les muestro una imagen de la ventana que me despliega en chrome, no me deja continuar ni siquiera pulsando en opciones avanzadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como dato adicional, mi Sistema operativo es Windows 7, pero este mismo error ya me había sucedido en Windows 10

Comment: Por si a alguien le sirve antes de solucionar mi problema encontré un truco el cual podría servirle a cualquiera, seleccionen la página correspondiente y tecleen "badidea", de esa manera pueden acceder a la página sin importar que la conexión sea o no privada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia el sufijo del dominio de .dev a .test, por ejemplo, ya que Chrome pide https a todos los dominios .dev.

Cambia de navegador. No tendrás este problema con FireFox.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue la solución, antes no tuve problemas con ese dominio.